# Why is the content of my UIScrollView scrolling behind my UIStackView?

Tags: swift

I made a ***StackView*** on top of my ***ScrollView***. The bottom constraint of my ***StackView*** is constrained to the top constraint of the ***ScrollView***. I use the ***ScrollView*** as a container to display my content. The ***StackView*** consists of 6 buttons and serves as a navigation. Hierarchy looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adX8n.jpg).

---

To add a new controller into my ***ScrollView*** I use the following code:

```
 @IBAction func planAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let newPlan = sender.frame.origin.x
    scrollView.subviews.forEach{$0.removeFromSuperview()}
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nextController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlansViewController2") as! PlansViewController2
    addChildView(viewController: nextController, in: scrollView)
    self.movingView.frame.origin.x = newPlan
}
```

---

```
public func addChildView(viewController: UIViewController, in containerView: UIView) {
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    viewController.view.frame = containerView.bounds
    addChildViewController(viewController)
    containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
    viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

---

In my ***PlansViewController*** I add a ***UIBarButtonItem*** programmatically but it is not displayed. Look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAf0e.jpg).

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
        if !viewControllers.contains(where: {
            return $0 is StructureNavigationListViewController }) {
            let filterBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Kategorienliste", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCategoryListTap(sender:)))
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [filterBtn]
        }
    }
```

Is my hierarchy wrong or what´s going on here?

Comment: Your problem is not showing `UIBarbuttonItem` or `UIScrollView` go behind your stack view ?

Comment: Sorry. Edited my question. BarButtonItem is not showing up.

Comment: @Nimrani1337 have you debug it and have you noticed this statement returns true?  **if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers**

Comment: use debug hierarchy in xcode first to know that if any ui item overlapping on your BarButtonItem item or its not added to your view

Comment: @Ram You mean like [this](https://imgur.com/a/SbJYhd1) ? It states: 0 values. What I do now? I never used the debugger before.

Comment: @A.Munzer how Im gonna do this exactly? I never used breakpoints before. How can I do it that way?